# PyTorch: Interpolate - Input and output must have the same number of spatial dimensions, but got input with spatial dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I am following a U-Net tutorial and I am currently stuck with some interpolation. My x comes as `[256, 16384]`. Which is a batch of 256 with 1 channel and the 128x128 is flatten to 16384.
Thus, I reshape x to `[256, 1, 128, 128].` Then I go for some transformations and my out prior to a reshape is [256, 1, 32, 32]. I reshape it to [256, 1, 32x32] and finally squeeze it to [256, 1296]. My print outs show me that everything until then is correct. Finally, I would like to interpolate back to [256, 16384].

```
  def forward(self, x):
      print(f'dim of x is {x.shape}')
      src_dims = (x.shape[0], 1, 128, 128)
      z = self.encoder(torch.reshape(x, src_dims))
      out = self.decoder(z[::-1][0], z[::-1][1:])
      out = self.head(out)
      out = torch.reshape(out, (out.shape[0], 1, out.shape[2] * out.shape[3]))
      out = torch.squeeze(out)
      print(f'shape of OUT PRIOR interpolate is {out.shape}')
      if self.retain_dim:
          out = F.interpolate(out, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1]))
      print(f'shape of OUT after squeeze is {out.shape}')
      z   = z[0]
      z = self.head(z)
      z = torch.squeeze(z)
      return out, z
```

My print-outs before interpolate are:

> dim of x is torch.Size([256, 16384])
> shape of OUT PRIOR interpolate is torch.Size([256, 1296])

so now I assume, if I plug it into F.interpolate, it should interpolate a [256, 1296] tensor to a [256, 16384] tensor.

nevertheless here is this error:

```
ValueError: Input and output must have the same number of spatial dimensions, 
but got input with spatial dimensions of [] and output size of (256, 16384). 
Please provide input tensor in (N, C, d1, d2, ...,dK) format and output size 
in (o1, o2, ...,oK) format.
```

Comment: Like the error message says, your input to F.interpolate needs to be NxCxHxW format. If your `out` is 256x1296 you need to unsqueeze it to 1x1x256x1296.